# Command prompt. Is it possible to create a certain number of variables according to the lines in a text file and then

Tags: command-line, batch-file, cmd.exe, environment-variables

Can we use a text file to set variables according to how many changing lines are there in the .txt file?

```
files.txt
  name 1
  text 2
  info 3
  ... and so on

set line01="name 1"
set line02="text 2"
set line03="info 3"
...and so on
```

and then later on, do a number sequencing and take this variables to a line like this:

```
command to do stuff  /
do stuff and copy %%seq01%% - %%line01%% /
do stuff and copy %%seq02%% - %%text02%% /
do stuff and copy %%seq03%% - %%info03%% /
```

I can't get my head around this, and there are more things things like this to be done, so if you could include a little explanation on t how it works I would really appreciatte. Thank you

Comment: Wouldn't it be easier using a programming language to accomplish this?  PowerShell perhaps?

Comment: Yes, it would.  @Gerard H. Pille

Comment: Then, will you give it a try?  Define a stuff function, read each line from files.txt and call stuff for each line found.

Comment: I guess I'll have to find out how to write that in Powershell, anyway this for loops are crazy and I want to get a grip on them @Gerard H. Pille

Comment: There's quite a number of good tutorials where you'll find what you need. Just make sure you understand what you're doing.

Comment: Use a `for /f` and `findstr /n` to get the lines into a (pseudo) array in cmd line `for /f "tokens=1* delims=:" %A in ('findstr /n "^" files.txt') do  set "Line[%A]=%B "&set Ln=%A` in a batch double all percent signs. In PowerShell it's as easy as `$Lines = Get-content files.txt` and to retrieve lines from a zero based index `$Lines[0..2]`

Comment: What does this "^" do in that line? @LotPings

Comment: By default findstr is in RegEx mode, the caret anchors at line begin, thus matching any line.